# Google Chrome Network Developer Tools - Form Data is missing from headers tabs on most sites

Tags: google-chrome, http, post, google-chrome-devtools

I recall being able to view POST request payloads/form data through the Google Chrome Network tool not a while back. I used to be able to see things like my Facebook and Craigslist login credentials when they were POSTed using the Form Data section of the Headers tab, but that Form Data section has seemingly disappeared. 
I don't know what happened but I have a few guesses:
1. Did Chrome remove this feature?
2. Can websites now include in the HTML markup a way to hide POST bodies from chrome dev tools?
3. Is the feature turned off somewhere in my settings where I can re-turn it on?

Automating a task and the project depends heavily on being able to view that post data. Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Try installing an older portable version of Chrome and see if it works. Also, try Chrome Canary.

Comment: The issue is being tracked here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766715#c4

Answer (score 6):

Good news, a fix has been commited to the repo, however it won't probably make it to v63 release, so we will likely have to wait for v64... The best way to get it ASAP is to get dev/[beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html) version of Chrome and wait till it arrives there. I will update this once it arrives into the public release of Chrome.

**Update:** It appears that this has been merged to v63 release, so it should be out very soon for all users.

Comment: Hmm... I have v67 and can't see the request body in the network logs